# DispatchGroup won't wait for function to complete

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to send every video from an album selected by the user to a local server which receives and stores them. But I can't get the upload function to execute after the video was exported, instead the first upload finishes after about 80 videos are already exported.
I use the following function:

```swift
    func copyAlbum(album: AlbumModel) {
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            total = Double(album.count)
        }
        var photoAssets = PHFetchResult<AnyObject>()
        photoAssets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: album.collection, options: nil) as! PHFetchResult<AnyObject>
        let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager()
        photoAssets.enumerateObjects{(object, count, stop) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                progress = Double(count)
            }
            if object is PHAsset {
                let asset = object as! PHAsset
                if(asset.mediaType == .video) {
                    let options = PHVideoRequestOptions()
                    options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
                    options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
                    options.version = .current
                    imageManager.requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: options, resultHandler: {avasset,_,_ in
                        let temporaryDirectoryURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(),
                                                        isDirectory: true)
                        let fileURL : URL = temporaryDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("asset"+String(count)+".mov")
                        let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession.init(asset: avasset!, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
                        exportSession?.outputURL = fileURL
                        exportSession?.outputFileType = .mov
                        exportSession?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
                            print("exported asset " + String(count))
                            group.enter()
                            uploadFile(url: URL(string: "http://"+localIP+":3000/upload")!, fileURL: fileURL, completionHandler: {success in
                                group.leave()
                                do {
                                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileURL)
                                } catch let error as NSError {
                                    print(error)
                                }
                            })
                        })
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            showProgress = false
        }
    }
```

It basically exports the video, saves it into the temp folder, calls the upload function and then deletes the video file.

This is my uploading file function:

```swift
   func uploadFile(url: URL, fileURL: URL, completionHandler: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void)) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url);
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let boundary = "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        print("uploading " + fileURL.lastPathComponent + "...")
        let fileData = try! Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        let body = NSMutableData()
        body.append(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
        body.append(NSString(format: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"api_token\"\r\n\r\n" as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
        body.append(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
        body.append(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"; filename=\""+fileURL.lastPathComponent as String+"\"\r\n" as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
        body.append(NSString(format: "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n").data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
        body.append(fileData)
        body.append(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
        
        request.httpBody = body as Data
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if data != nil {
                print("uploaded " + fileURL.lastPathComponent)
                completionHandler(true)
            } else if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completionHandler(false)
            }
        })
        
        task.resume()
    }
```

My console output is:

```
exported asset 0
uploading asset0.mov...
exported asset 1
uploading asset1.mov...
exported asset 2
uploading asset2.mov...
exported asset 3
uploading asset3.mov...
exported asset 4
uploading asset4.mov...
exported asset 5
uploading asset5.mov...
...
```

but I would expect

```
exported asset 0
uploading asset0.mov...
uploaded asset0.mov
exported asset 1
uploading asset1.mov...
uploaded asset1.mov
exported asset 2
uploading asset2.mov...
uploaded asset2.mov
...
```

This is probably a small mistake I made somewhere along the way and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `DispatchGroup` is never going to wait, not in this context. The pattern behaves like a counter, `enter` increments the counter (quasi synchronously) and `leave` decrements it after the asynchronous task completes. Finally `notify` is called when the counter reaches zero.

Comment: @vadian oh okay, do you have an idea on how I can wait for the upload to complete?

Comment: You can use OpeartionQueue for this. If you never worked with it, the guys at RayWenderlich have a good tutorial to get get started here https://www.raywenderlich.com/5293-operation-and-operationqueue-tutorial-in-swift

Comment: Or if you don't want to re-write your logic, I think you could use something like a recursive function which will get all the assets and an index and will export and upload the asset at that index, and when the upload is done you would call the function again with an increased index

Comment: @CosteaBogdan I actually switched to a recursive function and everything works perfectly now, thanks for your help :)

Comment: @vadian could the OP have used `group.wait()` at the end of the `photoAssets.enumerateObjects` block to get the behaviour they wanted?